# Write user input to a text file in Java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write user input to a text file. Below is what I have tried. I can't figure out what is wrong with this.

```
public class Source {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       String fileName = "write.txt";
       FileWriter FileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
       BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(FileWriter);

       System.out.println("Give an input to write to txt file");
       String input = Scanner.next();

       while(input != null){
         input = Scanner.next();
         System.out.println(input);    

         //bufferedWriter.write(input);
         //bufferedWriter.close();     
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Hearty That would make it a duplicate. Please flag it as one.

Comment: Thanks i fixed it.I need to use nextline(), instead of next().